# Record browsing history

Tags: browser, proxy, browser-cache

How can I record everything I browse so that, ideally, it might later enable me to re-surf the same pages without internet access ?
For instance, if I go to http://www.example.com/example.html I would like to be able to view the same page later exactly as initially (but without reconnecting to www.example.com). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has [extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/offline) which might help you in this.

[BetterCache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6371) could give you the effect you need.

If not, there's [Read It Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7661) and a newer one called [Read Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/78241)
There's also [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427)

Answer (score 1):

Also [Shelve](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8282) firefox extension

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky for dynamic web sites. For a largely static set of websites, then a [caching web proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) in front of your browser would help, beyond your browser's own built in caching. Also adjust your browser's caching to a large-ish size. Beyond that I don't have a good solution. dynamic and interactive web content isn't designed to be *snapshot*-able. Browsers with predictive pre-fetching help a small degree here, but otherwise you can re-walk your previous footsteps, assuming the http Cache tags are sane.

For a one-off user, this does fit better on SuperUser.com.